# Is this block matrix totally unimodular?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

Suppose matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m×n}$ has the consecutive ones property and, thus, is totally unimodular. Is the following block matrix also totally unimodular (TU)?

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 
       A & 0 & \dots & 0\\
       0 & A & \dots & 0\\
       \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
       0 & 0 & \dots & A\\
       I & I & \dots & I\end{pmatrix}$$

This type of matrix appears when dealing with the Coloring Problem over Interval Graphs, which can be solved in polynomial time, but I don't know if there is any result on the total unimodularity of such matrix.

A similar question was asked here ([Is this block matrix also totally unimodular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1969463)), where $A$ was known to be TU. In this case the block matrix can be non-TU, however the counter-example given uses a matrix A that does not have the consecutive one's property.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Thanks Rafael for pointing out in the comments below a counterexample which, unfortunately, invalidates any affirmative proof, including what I had mistakenly posted. The submatrix obtained in his counterexample is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Actually I have found a counter-example. Let A be the following matrix:
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
    I     & I     & I & I    \\
    M & {\bf 0} & {\bf 0} & {\bf 0}\\
    {\bf 0} & M &  {\bf 0} & {\bf 0}\\
    {\bf 0} & {\bf 0} & M & {\bf 0}\\
    {\bf 0} & {\bf 0} & {\bf 0} & M
\end{bmatrix}
where
    M = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Then consider the submatrix composed of rows rows 2,4,5,7,9 and columns 2,3,4,6,8. Such submatrix has determinant -2...

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. I misunderstood the definition of submatrices. Will try to update answer accordingly.